# Why does my Perl subroutine return false even though the parameters are valid?

Tags: perl, validation, parameters

I am trying to write a function which validates the username for an alphanumeric value and in the case of failure it should log my custom error message and return 0 to the called function instead of die-ing:

```
sub insertUser{
            my ( $username, $password, $email, $name) = validate_pos( @_, 
                   { type => SCALAR,
                     regex => qr/^\w+$/,
                     on_fail => { $err->error("username validation failed"),return 0 }  
                     },
                    { type => SCALAR },
                    { type => SCALAR },
                    { type => SCALAR ,optional => 1,default => 99});
            print "$username, $password, $email, $name ";
}
```

With the above code I am facing a problem like it's still returning 0 in the success case.
Can anybody please help me in this regard and could anyone explain me why it is doing so?

Comment: question title not question not capitalized unpunctuated nouns adjectives difficult reading

Comment: @user267074 See my edited answer below which returns '0' for failure.

Comment: It would have been helpful to note that you are using Params::Validate.

Comment: @Ether, that is where punctuation and capitalization would help.  @EVERYONE:  You aren't e e cummings or bell hooks. Please use punctuation and capitalization.

Comment: E.E. Cummings wasn't even e e cummings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback associated with `on_fail` is not supposed to return a value. It is supposed to `die` in some way.

In the [Params::Validate documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Params-Validate/lib/Params/Validate.pm#Options), is the following explanation for the `on_fail` callback:

> `on_fail => $callback`
>
> If given, this callback will be called
>   whenever a validation check fails. It
>   will be called with a single
>   parameter, which will be a string
>   describing the failure. This is useful
>   if you wish to have this module throw
>   exceptions as objects rather than as
>   strings, for example.
>
> *This callback is expected to die()
>   internally. If it does not, the
>   validation will proceed onwards, with
>   **unpredictable** results.*
>
> The default is to simply use the Carp
>   module's confess() function.

(emphasis mine)

The following code works by wrapping the validation routine in an `eval` block:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Params::Validate qw{ :all};
my $return_value = insertUser('user','password','user@example.com');  #passes
print "return value: $return_value\n";

my $error_return_value = insertUser('user*','password','user@example.com');  
print "error return value: $error_return_value\n";

sub insertUser{
     eval{
         my ( $username, $password, $email, $name) = validate_pos( @_, 
                { 
                  type    => SCALAR,
                  regex   => qr/^\w+$/,
                  on_fail => sub{ die "username validation failed"},  
                },
                { type => SCALAR },
                { type => SCALAR },
                { type => SCALAR ,optional => 1,default => 99});
         print "$username, $password, $email, $name \n";
     };
     if($@){
         return 0;
     }else{
         return 1;
     }
}
```

The output from this is:

```
user, password, user@example.com, 99
return value: 1
error return value: 0
```

Comment: firstly thanks for your response,could you tell that ,"is there any way it returns a value 0" in the case of failure instead of "die" in insert user funtion. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you remove the `eval` statement, then this code doesn't actually execute the `on_fail` function for Params::Validate version 1.0. Does anyone know how to get this actually working?